# Xcode 11 beta 6 behind Xcode 11 beta 7 download link?

Tags: xcode, xcode11

I have tried to download several times Xcode beta version which should be Xcode 11 beta 7 with iOS 13.1 beta support. I am downloading it from this link: https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_11_Beta_7/Xcode_11_Beta_7.xip

Also, when unpacking, it's obviously saying that it's unpacking Xcode 11 beta 7:

[image]

But after unpacking it (on 27th of August around 23:05), I am seeing following:

[image]

And when I start Xcode I see this:

[image]

Any ideas what might be happening?

Thanks in advance for any kind of answer.

Comment: My guess (which is _just_ a guess) is that this is a tiny tiny tweak to make the beta work with Catalina 13.1 which is about to appear.

Comment: Same issue, they forgot to rename version, check the build number

Comment: Yeah, I think this is what discussion pointed to and that's all fine, in theory the only thing which is missing is possibility to add 13.1 simulators. For the record, this version does run apps on devices with 13.1 beta OS installed.

Comment: Talk about sloppiness. My tipoff was when I opened the app and it didn't ask to "install needed components" - like **that** isn't always annoying (just do it). Yes, a different build. Hey, at least it's now at the same beta level as iOS (sarcasm intended).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My educated guess is that they just forgot to update the name.  Note that the About box says the build is 11M392r, which is what the download site says you're getting.  By the way, the beta 6 I have is 11M392q.

Comment: @JWWalker Thanks for the reply, but what's funny in there is that I have no option to add 13.1 simulators to it. Max it goes is 13.0, which is also Xcode 11 beta 6 characteristic.

Comment: Starting it up also doesn't trigger the installation of new components as all previous beta's have done.

Comment: On the other hand, SwiftUI previews crash in 11M392r, aka "beta 7", consistent with the beta 7 release notes: SwiftUI,
Known Issues,
Xcode Previews in Xcode 11 beta 7 have a known incompatibility with macOS Catalina beta 6. Upgrade to a newer macOS Catalina beta when available. (54621598). Have redownloaded and gone back to 11M392q (beta 6 proper) until I successfully installed a newer macOS Catalina beta.

Comment: @matt, the "educated" part is paying attention to the build number, not just 6 versus 7.

Comment: @RichardGroves My point exactly. Also it's just "q" vs "r" in the build number. A bit too little of a change.

Comment: Can confirm that after first installing macOS Catalina beta 7, Xcode 11M392r aka beta 7, no longer crashes SwiftUI previews. But it still doesn't allow adding iOS 13.1 simulators.

Comment: What's weird is the release date... 27 August on website but the extracted package has 22 august as the modification date

Comment: Right @HugoF the simulators of Xcode-beta (11M392r) are showing iOS 13.0 instead of 13.1

Answer (score 14):

The [release notes for Xcode 11 beta 7](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_7_release_notes) have been updated with:

1. Warning:
   Xcode Previews in Xcode 11 beta 7 have a known incompatibility with macOS Catalina beta 6. Upgrade to macOS Catalina beta 7 or later. (54621598) and
2. Known Issues:
   Xcode 11 beta 7 incorrectly reports as beta 6 on the welcome screen. (54795525)

Answer (score 6):

Looks like they forgot to change 6 to 7. And you need to rename 13.0 folder to 13.1 to support latest iOS beta (if you copy this folder to Xcode 10.3).